# Identifying columns with high correlation in large dataset

Tags: r

I have two large dataframes (50+ columns and many are long character vars) and I need to identify the "link" variable that I should use to merge them together. The problem is the name of the variables don't match up. That is I need to identify variables in the two datasets where the values have a high correlation.

As an example :

```
dta1 = data.frame(A = c(1 , 2,3, 4), B = c( 23, 45, 6, 8), C = c("001", "028", "076", "039"))
dta2 = data.frame(first = c(5, 6, 7, 8), second = c( 58, 32, 33, 45), third = c("008", "028", "076", "039"))
```

I would like the code to tell me that **columns C and third have a very high correlation** (they are not complete duplicates though!).

- I have tried adding the two dataframes and running a cor() function, but this doesn't work with character variables.
- Also tried union_all(x, y, ...) from dplyr but that requires the same column names.

At this point I am out of ideas.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Why the negative review? I've looked through all similar questions and none of them relate to this setup.

Comment: Could the people that are downgrading this comment pls point me to any questions that are similar to this? I've read through everything and cannot find any.

Comment: Two pieces of feedback. First, R cannot build your example data.frames because you have variables of different length. `A`, `B`, `first`, and `second` have four elements, and `C` and `third` each have three. All variables need to be the same length. Second, if you share either some code you have tried (but does not work) or what your expected output looks like, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks @BenNorris! I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the columns most similar, try the following. It systematically compares the values from each column in `dta1` with the columns in `dta2`. It returns a matrix.

```
sapply(dta1, function(x) sapply(dta2, function(y) sum(x == y)))
       A B C
first  0 1 0
second 0 0 0
third  0 0 3
```

From here we can see that `third` and `C` have the most matches. Now you can join your two data.frames. To keep all rows and columns, you will want a `full_join` from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(dta1, dta2, by = c("C" = "third"))
   A  B   C first second
1  1 23 001    NA     NA
2  2 45 028     6     32
3  3  6 076     7     33
4  4  8 039     8     45
5 NA NA 008     5     58
```